# PHP confirmation email

Tags: php, email, mailer

I have a registration form on my website, Upon completion the details are stored on CSV file but I also want to send a confirmation Email to the User. The issue is that the email arrives blank, what i have done is created a `template.php` file that contains the email structure that i want to send out, within this template structure i have function from other file that determines the registration date. the template within `template.php` is wrapped within  a function which i call in `from_to_csv.php` as part of mail() atrebiutes:

Hopefully this makes sense and you guys understand me have a look at the code:

**template.php**:

```
   <?php

function getMailContent(){

$subject = "OPES Academy- Workshop confirmation";
$message = "
<body style='background-color: #eeeeee; margin: 0 auto; font-family: 'lato',sans-serif'>

<table style='background-color:#ffffff' width='600' heigth='auto' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' align='center'>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table width='600' style='background-color: #5e8ab5;' align='center' cellpading='0' cellspacing='0'>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p style='padding-left: 20px;'><img src='http://opesacademy.com/emails/images/logo.png'
                                                            width='100' alt='Opes Academy'></p>
                    </td>
                    <td style='text-align: right; padding-right: 10px; color: #ffffff'>
                        KNOWLEDGE | WEALTH | POWER
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td style='padding: 10px;'>

            <h1 class='skinytxt text-center txtblue'>Thank you for reserving your place</h1>

                    <p>&nbsp;</p>

                    <p class='txt-white text-center'>Thanks for your registration, we will be looking forward to see you at the";

                     ?>
                     <?php
                        require('helper.php');
                        echo ConvertDate( $_SESSION['date'] );
                    ?>
                    <?php
 $message.="
                    <p align='center'>Address: 6 Thomas More Square, London, E1W 1XZ</p>

                    </p>

                    <p class='txt-white text-center'>If you have any more questions we will be glad to help you, just call us on 020 3675 9000 or email us on
                        support@opesacademy.com</p>

        </td>
    </tr>

</table>

<table width='600' style='background-color: #5e8ab5;' align='center' cellpading='0' cellspacing='0'>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p style='padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; font-size: 10px'>Trading and investing often
                involves a very high degree of risk. Past results are
                not indicative of future returns and financial instruments can go down as well as up
                resulting
                in you receiving less than you invested. Do not assume that any recommendations, insights,
                charts, theories, or philosophies will ensure profitable investment. Spread betting, trading
                binary options and CFD's carry a high risk to your capital, can be very volatile and prices
                may
                move rapidly against you. Only speculate with money you can afford to lose as you may lose
                more
                than your original deposit and be required to make further payments. Spread betting may not
                be
                suitable for all customers, so ensure you fully understand the risks involved and seek
                independent advice if necessary</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>";

$headers = "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

return compact($subject, $message, $headers);
}
?>
```

**form_to_csv.php**:

```
    $to = $data['email'];

   require('template.php');
$mailContent = getMailContent();

//csv
if(@$_POST['land']=='fw'){
    $path='/home/content/24/12131124/html/files/Admin/CSV_Binary/';
    $fName=$path.'free_workshop-'.date( "F_j_Y" ).".csv";
    //mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers,"-f info@opesacademy.com");
  mail($to, $mailContent['subject'], $mailContent['message'], $mailContent['headers'],"-f info@opesacademy.com");


}
```

`$to` variable contains the email that the user has inputed into the form.....

Comment: Did you try to print the output of `template.php` in a browser window?

Comment: It looks to me like you've redeclared PHPs `mail()` function with your own `mail()` function. Shouldn't this throw an error about trying to redeclare `mail`?

Comment: no no errors are thrown just the e-mail i blank but if i copy and past the email template code into the form_to_csv. php it works

Answer (score 2):

Your mail method does not return a thing.
Please add compact('headers', 'message', 'subject');

Then use the returned array in your other function.

```
<?php
// you might place the following method into mail.php

// formerly your mail function, renamed to avoid function name clash
// with PHP's own function mail
function getMailContent(){
   $subject = "OPES Academy- Workshop confirmation";
   $message = "Message";
   $headers = "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

   // return the things :)
   return compact('subject', 'message', 'headers');
}

// Usage:

// from_to_csv.php

// you need to include the file mail.php, 
// if you want to access the function  getMailContent()
// uncomment this line, if you split the PHP code into the files.
// include 'mail.php';    

// fetch mail content as array
$mailContent = getMailContent();

// access array values
mail($to, 
     $mailContent['subject'], $mailContent['message'], 
     $mailContent['headers'],
     "-f info@opesacademy.com"
);
?>
```

Comment: Where should i add the compact() on template.php like so: $send = compact($header, $message, $subject) and in form_to_csv mail($to, $send)....?

Comment: I've added a little example to demonstrate it.

Comment: I have sort of followed your instructions please check edits in my question, And I get this Error message:

Comment: We look forward to see you soon 
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/24/12131124/html/php/template.php:36) in /home/content/24/12131124/html/php/form_to_csv.php on line 201

Comment: Not sure where this error comes from. The example i posted should run out of the box, if you comment out the include statement and wrap it in PHP tags.

Comment: what do you mean comment out include statement and wrap it PHP tags

Comment: You do comment things out from PHP interpretation, by prepending "//" - the comment tags. By wrapping in PHP tags, i mean to add the PHP start and end tags "<?php" and "?>". I've adjusted my example accordingly..

Comment: Ok, i've seen that you updated your code. Please change "compact($subject, $message, $headers)" to "return compact('subject', 'message', 'headers');" - without the dollar signs and as normal string. That should do it...rest looks fine to me. Please post any errors.

Comment: Sorry for late replay I get this errom message:

Comment: 19th February 2014
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/24/12131124/html/php/template.php:36) in /home/content/24/12131124/html/php/form_to_csv.php on line 196

Comment: 'if(@$_POST['land']=='fw')header("Location: http://confirmation.php?camp=".$data['camp']);
 else header("Location: http//:confirmation.php?camp=".$data['camp']);'

Comment: Use headers_sent() to check, if headers are already sent and to avoid this error. Example: if (!headers_sent()) { header('Location: '.$url); }

Answer (score 0):

Local variables (in this case $message and $header) can't be accessed outside of the local function. This is called 'variable scope' and you should do some more reading on it (Here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

In this case $message and $header are being declared in the Local Scope: function mail() and you are trying to access them in the Global Scope when you call the PHP Mail function.

You must pass this back out of your function in order to access them in the form_to_csv.php file.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to access the $subject, $message and $headers variables from within your Mail() function, the will not be accessible unless you return them first... try this, In your template PHP put:

```
function MyMail() {
   // Your variables and content here


   return Array(
    "subject" => $subject,
    "message" => $message,
    "headers" => $headers;
   );
}
```

In your main file:

```
$to = $data['email'];

require('template.php');
$content = MyMail();

//csv
if(@$_POST['land']=='fw'){
    $path=='/home/content/CSV/';
    $fName=$path.'free_workshop-'.date( "F_j_Y" ).".csv";
     mail($to, $content["subject"], $content["message"], $content["headers"],"-f info@opesacademy.com");

}
```

Comment: This looks interesting I will try it but just to confirm $message = exactly the html template code correct...? so function myMail(){}

Comment: 'function myMail(){ $message = "<html><body><p>HELLO USER</p></body></html>" }'

Comment: Yes, essentially change the function name so it doesn't clash and just put the return Array at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

A super easy fix for this would be to just make template.php NOT a function.

delete the line

```
function mail(){
```

and then the ending curly bracket

```
}
```

and your script will run just fine.

Check http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php for more information